# how to put multiple markers on google map using address no latitude and longitude is provided?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, google-maps

I want in my application show multiple markers on google map .only address of the city or country is provided but without latitude and longitude of the city.any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**In PHP:**

`$address` will contains the address.

```
$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

This is in php and you can get lat and long.

**In Javascript:**

```
var address = //your address
var map = new google.maps.Geocoder();
map.geocode({'address' : address }, function(results, status){
    alert( "latitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() );
    alert( "longitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng() );
});
```

Comment: @francisdcunha Now check the answer this will help you sure.

Comment: hey bt i cant use php code in my application either actionscript or javascript

Comment: @gaurav  check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example    bt here latitude and logitude is privded in the array ,bt in my app only city name will be povided

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latitude and longitude of a city (or country) like this.

```
address_string = '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500';
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng(
    address_string,
    function(point) {
        if (point !== null) {
            alert(point); // or do whatever else with it
        } else {
            // error - not found, over limit, etc.
        }
    }
);
```

Note that I don't have a Google maps API key so I didn't have the time to test this.